# data studio - compare data from different columns

Tags: looker-studio

I have a table which records money spent on different things during a trip to a different city.[trip costs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWSkI.png)

It has date, city, and money spent on different things. Now I want to compare the cost in each category for a specific city. For example, city A. I want to make something like a pie chart, like the following

[image: sample pie chart]

However, I don't know if it is possible to make such pie chart from data in different columns.  If it is impossible, is there some other ways that I can visualise the comparison of different cost in one city in other types of charts or graphs?

Answer (score 2):

Since the amount expended is a related column (you may want to aggregate this data), you probably want to adjust your Data Source to something [like this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XZeAKXOxM3ZRzldXq8vm4uSaLgBgoesfd09eEmD1Pn8/edit?usp=sharing):

[image: Normalized Data Source]

This way, it will be easy to use standard Data Studio controls to break-down your dimensions, as follows:

[image: Pie chart using breakdown dimensions]

I made this report in Data Studio as an example:

- [Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/cc962899-bb00-4d18-bfbf-5ece5898ad4b)
- [Data Source used by the report](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XZeAKXOxM3ZRzldXq8vm4uSaLgBgoesfd09eEmD1Pn8/edit?usp=sharing)